# In F#, how does map2 handle uneven list lengths?

Tags: list, f#, map-function

How does the `map2` function handle uneven length lists?

e.g.

```
let list1 = [1; 2; 3]
let list2 = [4; 5; 6; 7]
let sumList = List.map2 (fun x y -> x + y) list1 list2
printfn "%A" sumList
```

It seems odd that this isn't mentioned in [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340232.aspx).

Comment: List.map2 throws an exception if you pass it lists with different size. It is easily checked in FSI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though the documentation doesn't cite it, one can easily check the [source code](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/0313094fa5d19fd871c83e7e45c35d1fad65daf9/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/local.fs#L113-L131) to find out what happens and the implementation details.

As you can see in the link, when you pass a list of different size, [invalidArg](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233178.aspx) is called, throwing an `ArgumentException` with the message stored in the `listsHadDifferentLengths` resource.